# Access view orientation from python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to access the alignment of the view from python? (e.g `'TOP'`, `'FRONT'`, `'RIGHT'`, etc.)

I looked in the api docs, but the closest I could find was [`view_perspective`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_0/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html?highlight=view_perspective#bpy.types.RegionView3D.view_perspective).

Comment: What about [`view_rotation`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_0/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html?highlight=view_perspective#bpy.types.RegionView3D.view_rotation)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of [`view3d.viewnumpad`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad) in `view3d_edit.c`, it's just `switch`-ing over `FRONT`, `BACK`, etc. enumerations and setting the view matrix accordingly. The only way I found is through deducing the orientation from view matrix in Python, in the following barebones example using either [`view_matrix`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D.view_matrix):

```
import math

def get_view_orientation_from_matrix(view_matrix):
    r = lambda x: round(x, 2)
    view_rot = view_matrix.to_euler()

    orientation_dict = {(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) : 'TOP',
                        (r(math.pi), 0.0, 0.0) : 'BOTTOM',
                        (r(-math.pi/2), 0.0, 0.0) : 'FRONT',
                        (r(math.pi/2), 0.0, r(-math.pi)) : 'BACK',
                        (r(-math.pi/2), r(math.pi/2), 0.0) : 'LEFT',
                        (r(-math.pi/2), r(-math.pi/2), 0.0) : 'RIGHT'}

    return orientation_dict.get(tuple(map(r, view_rot)), 'UNDEFINED')
```

... or [`view_rotation`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D.view_rotation) as @WChargin suggested, seeing that it's normalized as stated in API docs:

```
def get_view_orientation_from_quaternion(view_quat):
    r = lambda x: round(x, 3)
    view_rot = view_quat.to_euler()

    orientation_dict = {(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) : 'TOP',
                        (r(math.pi), 0.0, 0.0) : 'BOTTOM',
                        (r(math.pi/2), 0.0, 0.0) : 'FRONT',
                        (r(math.pi/2), 0.0, r(math.pi)) : 'BACK',
                        (r(math.pi/2), 0.0, r(-math.pi/2)) : 'LEFT',
                        (r(math.pi/2), 0.0, r(math.pi/2)) : 'RIGHT'}

    return orientation_dict.get(tuple(map(r, view_rot)), 'UNDEFINED')
```

It currently ignores perspective/orthogonal and camera view, but that can be easily deduced from the region's other variables.

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the pi/2 from? Those vectors aren't even normalized (e.g., `2pi^2/4 is not 1`). You probably mean `sqrt(2)` for the ones with two nonzero components and `1` for the ones with just one...

Comment: Especially considering the `#define M_SQRT1_2   0.70710678118654752440` in conjunction with `axis_set_view(C, v3d, ar, 0.0, 0.0, -M_SQRT1_2, -M_SQRT1_2, viewnum, nextperspo, align_active, smooth_viewtx);` (for example).

Comment: I get these constants the stupid way: executing each view shortcuts, and see the resulting matrix :D On second thought, maybe I should've used `view_rotation.to_euler()` as you suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Based on Adhi's solution, here's a complete operator to print all view3d perspectives like shown in the left-upper corner:

```
import bpy
import math


def main(context):
    view_orientations = []

    for area in context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            r3d = area.spaces.active.region_3d # fine for right-upper quadview view
            view_matrix = r3d.view_matrix

            view_orientation = get_view_orientation_from_matrix(view_matrix).capitalize()
            view_orientation += " " + r3d.view_perspective.capitalize()
            if area.spaces.active.local_view is not None:
                view_orientation += " (Local)"

            view_orientations.append(view_orientation)

    return view_orientations


def get_view_orientation_from_matrix(view_matrix):
    r = lambda x: round(x, 2)
    view_rot = view_matrix.to_euler()

    orientation_dict = {(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) : 'TOP',
                        (r(math.pi), 0.0, 0.0) : 'BOTTOM',
                        (r(-math.pi/2), 0.0, 0.0) : 'FRONT',
                        (r(math.pi/2), 0.0, r(-math.pi)) : 'BACK',
                        (r(-math.pi/2), r(math.pi/2), 0.0) : 'LEFT',
                        (r(-math.pi/2), r(-math.pi/2), 0.0) : 'RIGHT'}

    return orientation_dict.get(tuple(map(r, view_rot)), 'USER')


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        print("\n".join(main(context)))
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

Note: does only take the right-upper view in quadview mode into account.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's a clean way to do it.

Here's an excerpt of the painting code for the 3D viewport:

```
// view3d_draw.c:803
// in method: view3d_get_name
switch (rv3d->view) {
    case RV3D_VIEW_FRONT:
        if (rv3d->persp == RV3D_ORTHO) name = IFACE_("Front Ortho");
        else name = IFACE_("Front Persp");
        break;
    case RV3D_VIEW_BACK:
        if (rv3d->persp == RV3D_ORTHO) name = IFACE_("Back Ortho");
        else name = IFACE_("Back Persp");
        break;
    // etc ...
}
return name;
```

As you can see, it's simply checking these manually and looking them up (the `IFACE_` is for localization). The string is never stored in a value anywhere.

You could perform a similar check in Python using the [`view_rotation`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html?highlight=view_perspective#bpy.types.RegionView3D.view_rotation) property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105576/732016) for a starting point.