# WASD navigation and editing

Tags: scripting, edit-mode, scene

I know WASD navigation is possible in [walk/fly mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html), but you cannot edit from within that mode. Do you think a scripting addon could accomplish this functionality (I could write one)? Does one exist already? My problem is "fine navigation", as, for example, going easily into a "house" and editing the interior.

EDIT: I think the question is almost irrelevant, as WASD would interfere with many shortcuts in both EDIT and OBJECT mode. I will leave this question, if someone comes up with a similar problem and needs clarification. A solution is possible by editing the 3D view's view matrix or view quaternion. Some pointers are [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/access-view-orientation-from-python), but the problem of intercepting keys/mouse remains unsolved.

Comment: "and the viewpoint you arrive at is not retained when you exit it." I don't really understand this. If you mean that viewport doesn't save viewpoint posiiton reached in walk/fly mode then it does, just press LMB for exiting of the mode instead of Esc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my question, please retain your comment, so others can benefit.