# How can I check if view axis is "top", "bottom" etc?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

For example, using this `bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='TOP')` I can set `view axis` to "TOP". But how can I get current `view axis`?

Something like this for example:

```
if bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis == 'TOP':
    # Do something...
```

Please note: the question is about finding view axis, but not about to know if the view is perpective or orthographic.

Comment: Not sure the indicated duplicate corresponds to what is asked here...

Comment: @lemon exactly and thank you!!! Because I am **not asking** how to check if my current view is **orthographic**, **perspective** or **camera**. **But** if it is **top**, **bottom** etc!!!

Comment: In between... is it to use in an operator? I mean, there can be several 3D views.

Comment: I will need it for an operator too... Now I want to use it into a panel, like `if bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis == 'TOP':`

Comment: You think I have to make it as a new question?

Comment: In the context of a 3D view, you can (in operator `execute`, not sure that will go well in comments...): `        region = context.space_data.region_3d matrix = region.view_matrix.inverted() print("location", matrix.translation) print("rotation", matrix.to_euler())`

Comment: No, no new question. @batFINGER will correct that when he can.

Comment: I tried your code and I get this in console... `location <Vector (-0.0000, -0.0912, 0.9273)>` and `rotation <Euler (x=1.5708, y=0.0000, z=-0.0000), order='XYZ'>`

Comment: Yes. Don't think you can test what you want with 'TOP' or other keyword. Though the rotation part can allow you to check the view direction. (FYI your question is probably a dup, really, but was not able to find it...)

Comment: Wait... Since `bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='TOP')` for example, set viewpoint to top, why I can't check if viewpoint is "TOP", "BOTTOM" etc? For example if you `print` this `context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective` you get 'PERSP', 'ORTHO' or 'CAMERA'. Shouldn't exist something similar for `view_axis`?

Comment: Don't think this exists. As you can deduce what have been asked with bpy.ops from view_matrix or view_rotation + view_perspective. The bpy.ops parameter is a convenience. Link to the doc: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html

Comment: Yes sorry I posted the wrong link should have been this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/access-view-orientation-from-python  Will re-open could someone else vote to close please.

Comment: @batFINGER: Is there any question which explains how can I make it update in real time, when I click out of panel for example?