# Viewport Z rotation relative to 3D cursor

Tags: python, 3d-view, transforms, 3d-cursor

I'm trying to append an object so that it is placed at the 3D cursor and rotated in the Z axis so that it is facing the viewport. I can set the location easily like this:

```
object.location = context.scene.cursor.location
```

But how do I get the Z rotation of the viewport camera relative to the 3D cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Get z rotation of the viewport

```
import bpy, math

def find_area():
    try:
        for a in bpy.data.window_managers[0].windows[0].screen.areas:
            if a.type == "VIEW_3D":
                return a
        return None
    except:
        return None

area = find_area()

if area is None:
    print("area not find")
else:
    r3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d
    z = r3d.view_rotation.to_euler().z

    print(" Z rotation of the viewport is: ")
    print("     radians: ", z)
    print("     degrees: ", math.degrees(z))
```

Comment: more info:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265693/how-can-you-find-the-position-and-rotation-direction-of-the-viewport/265709#265709