# Get the viewing angle of a 3D viewport

Tags: python, scripting

How can i get the viewing angle of a 3D viewport in blender 3.0

Comment: get viewport data: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265693/how-can-you-find-the-position-and-rotation-direction-of-the-viewport/265709#265709

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Camera*
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to snap it to your viewport
3. <kbd>N</kbd> (or object properties) to see the transform location and rotation of your Camera

Comment: I meant the angle of the viewport.