# Set Orthographic-Top view with python?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, orthographic

I have tried to write a script to set the 3d view to the top view and also turn it in into an orthogonal projection

The closest I have got to the objective is based on this code found in this [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149835/set-orthographic-view-using-python) which can set the view to Top, however, it won't change the projection to an orthogonal one.

```
import bpy
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(override, type='TOP')
        break
```

I have found that the following code is listed as the operation that flips perspective into ortogonal view, however I have been unable to implement it without raising errors.

```
bpy.ops.view3d.view_persportho()
```

Comment: You can access and modify the `view_matrix` directly.  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265693/how-can-you-find-the-position-and-rotation-direction-of-the-viewport/265709#265709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this updated solution the view is toggled to orthogonal only if the view is already set to perspective projection.

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override["area"] = area
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(override, type='TOP', align_active=False) 
        if  area.spaces.active.region_3d.is_perspective:
            bpy.ops.view3d.view_persportho(override)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Note you don't need `else: pass` here