# How to temporarily save View state in order to return 3D View to how it was before running script

Tags: python, 3d-view

Pertaining to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290437/set-orthographic-top-view-with-python), from which I got the following code to change the 3D View to orthographic top view for the purposes of projecting and snapping vertices to other objects in preparation for texture baking:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override["area"] = area
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(override, type='TOP', align_active=False) 
        if  area.spaces.active.region_3d.is_perspective:
            bpy.ops.view3d.view_persportho(override)
```

How could I "save" the 3D View parameters as they are before running the script so I can then return the user to their original view when the baking is complete?

Comment: Hello ! I don't know if this will solve your problem but this should help you https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250935/86891

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you! There's a lot to get through there. I'd best get reading!